# Displaying an image in a VBScript MsgBox

Tags: image, vbscript, msgbox

How can I display an image in a MsgBox?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want is called a HyperText Application, or HTA.  You use HTML to create the form.

Comment: yeah I have made a question about making a dialogbox and someone mentioned the same thing you did. thanks for the help I will definitely  practice this language as well.

Answer (score 3):

The answer is: This is not possible. `MsgBox` can only display strings. ([Documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sfw6660x%28v=vs.85%29.aspx))

An alternative is to display your image in a small Internet Explorer window. Here's an example:

```
Set objExplorer = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")

With objExplorer
    .Navigate "about:blank"
    .ToolBar = 0
    .StatusBar = 0
    .Left = 100
    .Top = 100
    .Width = 200
    .Height = 200
    .Visible = 1
    .Document.Title = "Important image!"
    .Document.Body.InnerHTML = _
        "<img src='http://sstatic.net/stackoverflow/img/venn-diagram.png' height=100 width=100>"
End With
```

This should display the Venn diagram found in Stack Overflow's [about](https://stackoverflow.com/about) section.